# Divison of multi class into binary class using libsvm (not classification)

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I am working on multi class imbalance data.I want to divide my classes based on one verus one method and then perform sampling techinque. How can I do that I just want to divide the classes not classification. Is it possible in libsvm or to do manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is an easy method you can to do it by simple matlab code 
If you have multiple classes you and follow this process:

1.first read each class and store it in different cells.

2.second the combine each class with other class based on your methods example :If you use One verus One method combine each cell with other cell ..